# how to make a robust image gallery like facebook

Tags: gallery, image-gallery, photo-gallery, concept, imagedownload

i am trying to make a image gallery like facebook one thing which troubling me a lot that how can i make image viewer robust as in facebook if a have hundreds of image in a gallery how can i increase gallery performance.

> Is there any magic facebook do to robust its image gallery

need some good article and community guidance, and what is the actual concept behind this, or is there any very high image compressing algo which reduces images bytes.

Thanks all for your precious time

Comment: You could read about Facebook server farms, there's extreme brute force behind